# Can fragment color exceed the range [0,1] in GLSL?

Tags: glsl

In a fragment shader, can I set the output of gl_fragcolor to be

```
gl_fragcolor = vec4(5,5,5,1);
```

to make it a lot brighter, or is a fragment's maximum color value always clamped to 1? I want to achieve a bloom effect, and the first reply in a thread said that an 'attribute' is not clamped. 
The link is the following:
http://www.idevgames.com/forums/thread-941.html

Answer (score 2):

It depends entirely on what you have the fragment program output bound to.  If it is bound to a normal frame buffer that clamps to [0,1], then it will be clamped to [0,1].  If, on the other hand, you bind to some high dynamic range renderbuffer that does not clamp, then it won't be clamped.