# Sphere not rendering properly in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering

I am trying to render a sphere using OpenGL ES 3.0, with the FragColor being equal to the normals of the sphere, but due to some reason I am seeing the inner circles(horizontal circles) in the sphere, What might be the issue here?

[image: Sphere Image]

I am also attaching my generating vertex code of the sphere.

```
if(sphereVAO == 0){
    struct Vertex {
        float x, y, z;  // Position
        float nx, ny, nz;  // Normal
        float u, v;  // UV coordinates
    };

    std::vector<Vertex> vertices;
    int stacks = 30;
    int slices = 30;
    float radius = 1.0f;


for (int stack = 0; stack <= stacks; ++stack) {
    float phi = stack * M_PI / stacks;  // Azimuthal angle
    float sinPhi = sin(phi);
    float cosPhi = cos(phi);

    for (int slice = 0; slice <= slices; ++slice) {
        float theta = slice * 2 * M_PI / slices;  // Polar angle
        float sinTheta = sin(theta);
        float cosTheta = cos(theta);

        float x = cosTheta * sinPhi;
        float y = cosPhi;
        float z = sinTheta * sinPhi;

        float nx = x;
        float ny = y;
        float nz = z;

        float u = static_cast<float>(slice) / slices;
        float v = static_cast<float>(stack) / stacks;

        vertices.push_back({x * radius, y * radius, z * radius, nx, ny, nz, u, v});
    }
}

std::vector<Vertex> sphereVertices;
int numSlices = slices + 1;

for (int stack = 0; stack < stacks; ++stack) {
    for (int slice = 0; slice < slices; ++slice) {
        int currRow = stack * numSlices;
        int nextRow = (stack + 1) * numSlices;

        // Add two triangles
        sphereVertices.push_back(vertices[currRow + slice]);
        sphereVertices.push_back(vertices[nextRow + slice]);
        sphereVertices.push_back(vertices[currRow + slice + 1]);

        sphereVertices.push_back(vertices[nextRow + slice]);
        sphereVertices.push_back(vertices[nextRow + slice + 1]);
        sphereVertices.push_back(vertices[currRow + slice + 1]);
    }
}

    GLuint vbo;
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sphereVertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex), sphereVertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &sphereVAO);
    glBindVertexArray(sphereVAO);

    // Enable the vertex attributes
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);  // Position attribute
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);  // Normal attribute
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);  // UV attribute

    // Specify the attribute pointers
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), reinterpret_cast<const void*>(offsetof(Vertex, x)));
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), reinterpret_cast<const void*>(offsetof(Vertex, nx)));
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), reinterpret_cast<const void*>(offsetof(Vertex, u)));

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, static_cast<GLsizei>(sphereVertices.size()));
    num_sphere_indices = static_cast<GLsizei>(sphereVertices.size());
}
else{
    // glBindVertexArray(sphereVAO);
    // glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, num_sphere_indices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(sphereVAO);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, num_sphere_indices);
}
```

Comment: _FragColor being equal to the normals of the sphere_ That means r, g, b will have values in the range [**-1**, 1] but they should have values in the range [**0**, 1] (and [they are clamped to that range](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30990693/7478597)). You should use instead `n * 0.5 + 0.5`. Btw. please, [edit] and add your shader code as well.

Comment: Still why inner Circles(triangles) are visible?

Comment: @Palash That is called Z-fighting, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting. It is not apparent from your code, but is depth testing enabled?

Comment: @ErdalKüçük Depth Testing is enabled and still I am facing the issue, might be my sphere vertex generation has some bug?

Answer (score 0):

Your image looks typical of an issue with depth testing : the inner slices are somehow drawn after the sphere shell, and are not properly discarded by the depth test.

Without seeing the relevent code, I can only say that you could ensure that :

1. the depth test is enabled : `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`
2. the depth buffer is properly written to : `glDepthMask(GL_TRUE)`
3. the depth buffer is properly cleared : `glClean(...|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)`
4. the depth buffer actually exist : either on the `GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT` if you render in a FBO, or on the window framebuffer (platform dependent).